# Operator>> Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am implementing a complex number using operator overloading. In the program, the user enters a complex number ALWAYS in the form:

```
a + bi
```

So, in example...

```
25.0 + 3.6i
```

Assume that the user will always enter both the real and the imaginary parts of the complex number, e.g., the user will enter "5 + 0i" (and not "5") or "0 - 6.2i" (and not "-6.2i").

My problem is that in main() I have the following code:

```
ComplexNumber c1;
cin >> c1;
cout << c1;
```

and the code prints:

```
0 + 0i
```

...when I entered "4.2 + 8.3i" into the prompt during runtime.

Here is my implementation of my `operator>>` class:

```
istream & operator>>(istream & in, ComplexNumber & n) {
    string real;
    string imag;
    bool done = false;
    int sign = 1;

    string num;
    in >> num;

    int length;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        if (num.at(i) == 'i') {
            imag = num.substr((i - length), i);
        }
        else if (num.at(i) == '-') {
            sign = -1;
        }
        else if (num.at(i) == ' ') {
            if (!done) {
                real = num.substr(i);
                done = true;
            }
            length = 0;
        }
        length++;
    }

    n = ComplexNumber(atof(real.c_str()), atof(imag.c_str()) * sign);
    return in;
}
```

Here is my implementation of `operator<<` class:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const ComplexNumber & n) {
    n.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

Here is my implementation of the ComplexNumber member class print():

```
void ComplexNumber::print(ostream & out) const {
    if (imag >= 0)
        out << real << " + " << imag << "i";
    else 
        out << real << " - " << (-1 * imag) << "i";
}
```

This is my ComplexNumber header file for further details:

```
#ifndef COMPLEXNUMBER_H
#define COMPLEXNUMBER_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ComplexNumber {

  public:

    // constructors
    ComplexNumber();
    ComplexNumber(double real_part, double imaginary_part);
    ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber & rhs);

    // named member functions
    void print(ostream & out = cout) const;
    bool equals(const ComplexNumber & rhs) const;

    // assignment operators
    const ComplexNumber & operator=(const ComplexNumber & rhs);
    const ComplexNumber & operator+=(const ComplexNumber & rhs);
    const ComplexNumber & operator-=(const ComplexNumber & rhs);
    const ComplexNumber & operator*=(const ComplexNumber & rhs);

  private:
    double real;      
    double imag; 
};

// arithmetic operators
ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber & lhs, const ComplexNumber & rhs);
ComplexNumber operator-(const ComplexNumber & lhs, const ComplexNumber & rhs);
ComplexNumber operator*(const ComplexNumber & lhs, const ComplexNumber & rhs);

// relational operators
bool operator==(const ComplexNumber & lhs, const ComplexNumber & rhs);
bool operator!=(const ComplexNumber & lhs, const ComplexNumber & rhs);

// I/O operators
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const ComplexNumber & n);
istream & operator>>(istream & in, ComplexNumber & n);

#endif
```

Any help with my implementations would be great.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this [once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323943/overloading-operator)?

Comment: I asked something similar but it wasnt concise. So i deleted that one and made a more appropriate question.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a good example of concise...

Comment: How about [std::complex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/complex/)? (edit: add link)

Comment: Also, you should *edit* the original question, not delete it and create a new one.

Comment: you should debug it to see where _exactly_ the problem is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially your `operator >>` is way too complex, and doesn’t even handle errors properly. You shouldn’t read the value into a string to begin with – read it directly into a number. Furthermore, after each read operation you need to check (and potentially *set*) the stream’s state.

```
istream& operator >>(istream& in, ComplexNumber& value) {
    int re;
    if (not (in >> re)) {
        return in;

    char pm;
    if (not (in >> pm) or (pm != '+' and pm != '-') {
        in.setstate(ios::failbit);
        return in;
    }

    int im;
    if (not (in >> im))
        return in;

    char i;
    if (not (in >> i) or i != 'i') {
        in.setstate(ios::failbit);
        return in;
    }

    value = ComplexNumber {re, (pm == '-' ? -im : im)};
    return in;
}
```

(I used C++11 initialisers because I’m lazy ….)

And, yes, this can be written even shorter by pulling the whole reading into a single chainged expression:

```
istream& operator >>(istream& in, ComplexNumber& value) {
    int re;
    int im;
    char pm;
    char i;

    if (not (in >> re >> pm) or
        (pm != '+' and pm != '-') or
        not (in >> im >> i) or
        i != 'i')
    {
        in.setstate(ios::failbit);
        return in;
    }

    value = ComplexNumber {re, (pm == '-' ? -im : im)};
    return in;
}
```

Whether this is better depends on the audience. Personally, I do find it more (!) readable than the first version. A more structured alternative (which would be overkill for such a simple case) is [Boost.Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi_and_karma.html) which allows very elegant parser construction.

Comment: would you care to explain the ComplexNumber {re, (pm == '-' ? -im : im)}? as in what it is doint?

Comment: @Pat As I said, that’s a C++11 style initialiser, it’s equivalent to your constructor (which I was too lazy to write in my test code).

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
string num;
in >> num;
```

It reads only one word from input. You would need to call it several times to read something like `4.2 + 8.3i`, which has three words.

Comment: so you are saying that "in >> num" doesn't take input until the user hits enter? It separates at any white space?

Comment: you should use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) instead